# ! [remote rejected] v1.0.18 -> v1.0.18 (missing necessary objects)

Tags: git, tags

i'am try to push the latest git tag to remote repository but it is failed with the below error:
! [remote rejected] v1.0.18 -> v1.0.18 (missing necessary objects)
but yesterday work fine today not work
please help

Comment: Try fetching first, just in case?

Comment: i already make fetch: git fetch --tags but it is not work i used the script for this link https://gist.github.com/CSTDev/08c127680e3b5fae38c051da3e489351

Comment: What about fetching without `--tags`?

Comment: still the same error and used fetch --all but the same issue

Comment: i have 3 private repository the script work on 2 repository but failed on only 1 repository

Answer (score 0):

A "missing necessary objects" error generally indicates a bug in Git.

If you can expose the various repositories, or produce a new set of repositories that reproduce the problem, you can report this to the Git mailing list.

Comment: i have 3 private repository the script work on 2 repository but failed on only 1 repository

Comment: `git push` involves *two* repositories: the one that you're sending from (e.g., on your laptop), and the one you're sending to (e.g., on the corporate server). The error/bug could be in either repository or Git software. You'll need to make both versions of Git and/or both repositories available, or produce a repository-pair that reproduces the problem with a single version of Git.